# Wordpress Custom tables plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

How to resolve this warning which is shown when I use "**custom tables**" plugin for Wordpress?
Can anybody help me please

**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ..\wp-content\plugins\custom-tables\pages\show_table.php on line 378**

URL of this plugin
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-tables/

Comment: This error most probably occured if the table is empty. http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/custom-tables is the official support for the plugin.

Comment: but my table is not empty no help given on this official support

Answer (score 1):

The `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` is obtained when the element pased in the `foreach()` is not an array. For this plugin, at line 378:

```
foreach ($qry as $row) {
```

You can test if it is an array before passing through the foreach loop:

```
if ( is_array($qry ))
{
  foreach ($qry as $row) {...}
}
else die('not an array');
```

However, I encourage you to ask from the plugin support forum. The author can fix the plugin (assuming it's a problem with the plugin itself). Modifying the core of a plugin yourself is not advisable and consequently updating that plugin will overwrite your changes.